# Redis atomic GET and EXPIRE

Tags: redis

Is there an atomic `GET` + `EXPIRE` command available for Redis? This would act as a sliding expiration value: attempt to get the value specified by the key, and then **only if the key was found with this request**, set the time to live for X seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't, but there's nothing preventing you from sending the two commands one after the other in a `MULTI/EXEC` block or using a Lua script. Using `EXPIRE` on a non-existent key does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Or, I use simple Lua script:

```
local val, err = redis.pcall('GET', KEYS[1])
if err then
    return err
end
redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
return {val}
```

In Golang you can do:

```
import "github.com/go-redis/redis"

const lua = `
local val, err = redis.pcall('GET', KEYS[1])
if err then
    return err
end
redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
return {val}
    `

redisGetEx = redis.NewScript(lua)
result, err = redisGetEx.Run(redisClient, []string{"key"}, 1800).Result()
```